# Java 8 SSL issues - works properly with Java 7

Tags: java-8, ssl-certificate, keystore, pkcs#12, jks

I am consuming a web service which uses SSL certificate, they have provided PKCS12 certificate. Generated JKS using keytool, certificate is working fine in SOAPUI.

My project is using Java 8, but when I try to invoke service using JKS it shows **com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Rejected by policy.**

Tried same with Java 7, it is working fine and getting response from the service. Below is the code

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

KeyManagerFactory kmf =KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(new FileInputStream ("MYCLIENTCERT.JKS"), "keystorepassword".toCharArray() );
kmf.init( ks, "sourcepassword".toCharArray() );
sc.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null );

((BindingProvider) bp).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory",sc.getSocketFactory() );
```

PKCS12 given directly in java 7, that also working fine, not in Java8 (jdk1.8.0_131)

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream ("filename.p12"), "sourcepassword".toCharArray() );
    kmf.init( ks, "sourcepassword".toCharArray() );
```

Have tried so many option but seems nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the certificate in the PKCS12 signed by a known CA, or is it signed by their own CA?

Comment: I guess it is signed by their own CA

Comment: I think issue with binding provider, it is a SOAP service. Project deployed in CXF, I tried to change to Axis also, still no response. So now I changed code to HttpPost, I am able to get response, parsing headache is there.  As a standalone Java project response getting in Java7 but not in Java8.

Comment: If it is signed by their own CA, you need to set the `TrustManager` (second argument) in the `sc.init(...)` method. You need to construct a `TrustStore` with the CA Certificate chain, and construct a `TrustManager` instance using `TrustManagerFactory` and pass it as the second argument in the `init` method.

Comment: Tried that option as well, same certificate working with Okhttp and http client.       SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("file.p12"));
keyStore.load(instream, "password".toCharArray());
kmf.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()).build();

Comment: If you are working with self-signed certs, you need to pass in the TrustManager in the `sc.init(...)` method. I don't see you passing it in the above comment.

Comment: Just an update, it got fixed already when I change http client jar to httpclient-  4.5.2